# Ensurity of script execution or kick it if scheduled missed

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

OS: Ubuntu

Current Scenario: I have a bash script that is scheduled to run daily 12pm, Only one time per day. It fetches users lists from mysql table  whose accounts expiry is Today's date & disables them in various mysql table, and sends email alerts as well.

Problem: Sometimes it happens that script miss its schedule either due to server was down, or got rebooted at 12pm.

Therefore I am looking for some logic / method that the script should run every hour and it should check following

If it was executed today successfully at 12pm already , then don't RE-RUN,
If it was not executed then then it should execute the script on next run & dont re-run for that date again

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the state of last successful run. I think you can achieve in two ways:

- Create a new table in the mysql to store this information and store the last `datetime` when script ran successfully. Every 1hr script wakes up and look at this timestamp to do any pending actions.
- You could also store this information in some system folder like "/var/log/" or something that your application has access to and you need to sure that this file will not be removed across reboot.

Have this logic at the beginning of the file:

```
last_time_run = <fetch_from_db or persistant file>
current_time = <get_current_time>

if <already executed>; then
   don't do anything and exit. 
else
   processed and do normal actions.
fi


# End of the script
Update the timestamp in table or db to indicate that for current day the processing is finished.
```

Comment: I made an table like this.
 
id - script_name   -   lastupdate
2  - myscript         -  2018-06-25 15:48:25

whenever the script is running, its updating above table.

I want to make sure that script runs only 1 time a day at 12 pm, and if it misses schedule then re - run

Comment: I am lost in logic , 
the script should run code only one time per day 12 pm only

, but if it misses the schedule then it should run the code , 

and it should not run the code again for same date.

Comment: @iBBi you can upvote the answer if the answer solved your question.

Comment: Ok , I have managed to add the check that if the script was already executed in current date, then dont re-run. its hourly scheduled. this part is done.

But how can I force it to execute the actual code (which do my stuff) if the time is 12:00pm only? I have done this as well to match time, but but if 12pm run is is missed, then howto force script to run the code ?

Following is the script code , Paste-bin Link.

https://pastebin.com/wqLF0PVM